# Aligning content (e.g. a header from fancyhdr) horizontally with the right column

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I haven't seen this asked anywhere here yet but I still think it might be useful for people attempting to create slightly more complex layouts.

The idea is pretty simple, I'm trying to align content to the second column of my `multicols` environment.

In the example below I've included an example of such content in the form of a header, by adjusting dimensions manually. Obviously this impedes the workflow if you want to set a different `\columnsep`, change the size of one of the columns, etc.

To make the example a little clearer, I've included an image (accompied by code to compile the same document). Both the content from the header as well as the content from the column should align horizontally, but my way of getting it done here requires manual adjustment of dimensions.

What's a better practice (and/or easier) way to get this kind of result?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JRhEavq.png]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr}

% sample text
\def\sA{Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.}%
\def\sB{Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war.}%
\def\sC{We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.}%
\def\sD{It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.}%
\def\sE{But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate, we can not consecrate, we can not hallow this ground.}%
\def\sF{The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract.}%
\def\sG{The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.}%
\def\sH{It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.}%
\def\sI{It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us―--that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion―that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain―that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom―and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.}%
\edef\txt{\sA\ \sB\ \sC\ \sD\ \sE\ \sF\ \sG\ \sH\ \sI\ }
\edef\Txt{\txt \txt \txt}

% something to mimic the desired result visually
\columnsep=50pt%
\fancypagestyle{x}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
\hbox to 197pt{\hfill \rlap{\leftmark}}% I just guessed this value
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{x}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{My example section}]
\Txt
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I truly hope that `x` is not the real name of the pagestyle! Also, as a side note: `\hbox to 197pt{\hfill \rlap{\leftmark}}` is in the end the same `\hspace*{197pt}\rlap{\leftmark}}` or (IMHO better) `\hbox to 197pt{\hss \leftmark}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` (or `\makebox`, but `\parbox` is better) with `\columnwidth` in `\fancyhead[R]` instead of `\fancyhead[L]`.

```
\fancypagestyle{x}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[R]{%
\parbox{\columnwidth}{\leftmark}% no guessing
}%
}%
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr}

% sample text
\def\sA{Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.}%
\def\sB{Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war.}%
\def\sC{We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.}%
\def\sD{It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.}%
\def\sE{But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate, we can not consecrate, we can not hallow this ground.}%
\def\sF{The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract.}%
\def\sG{The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.}%
\def\sH{It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.}%
\def\sI{It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us―--that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion―that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain―that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom―and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.}%
\edef\txt{\sA\ \sB\ \sC\ \sD\ \sE\ \sF\ \sG\ \sH\ \sI\ }
\edef\Txt{\txt \txt \txt}

% something to mimic the desired result visually
\columnsep=50pt%
\fancypagestyle{x}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[R]{%
\parbox{\columnwidth}{\leftmark}% % no guessing
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{x}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{My example section}]
\Txt
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harish Kumar. I will go through a few iterations this weekend to see how I am going to implement your answer. I will accept regardless whether I did so succesfully, but not accepting it yet makes finding the question easier. I hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: @1010011010 Certainly no. Take your time.